# _.throttle executing API more than once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, request, lodash, throttling

I have a **TimeLine** component that renders posts 5 at a time

and when the user scrolls to the end of the page the throttle function is called.

I am trying to throttle the request to a maximum of once per second but The API is called multiple times

I tried several solutions like:

- making a global flag that won't let you use the function unless a certain timeout has passed "It doesn't make sense because I am using the throttle to do that but I tried to check if my implementation is wrong"
- declaring the throttle function alone outside the component

TimeLine.js

```js
export default function TimeLine() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const posts = useSelector(state => state.postReducer.posts);
    const loaded = useSelector(state => state.postReducer.loaded);
    const TIMEOUT = 1000;
    
  // Loaded keeps track of loaded posts
    if(loaded === 0){
        API.Post.getAllPosts(loaded)(dispatch);
    }

    if(loaded > 5){
        if(loaded % 5 === 0) window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight * 0.6)
        
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => throttledReq(loaded, TIMEOUT, dispatch));
    
    const classes = useStyle();
    return (
        <div>
            <NewPost  />

            {(posts && posts.length > 0)?posts.map((post, index) => (
                <div key={post._id} className={classes.post}>
                    <Post
                        currentIndex={index}
                        {...post.user}
                        dispatch={dispatch}
                        postID={post._id}
                        postContent={post.text}
                    />
                </div>
            )): false}
        </div>
    );
};
```

the Throttle function

```js
const throttledReq = (loaded, TIMEOUT, dispatch) => _.throttle(e => {
    const bottomLimit = document.documentElement.offsetHeight - window.innerHeight;
    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop === bottomLimit){
            API.Post.getAllPosts(loaded)(dispatch);
    }
}, TIMEOUT)();
```

My requests

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you scroll, you fire `dispatch`, which in turn re-runs the component, adding another event listener. This will continue infinitely.

You'll only want the event listener to be added the first time the component is rendered. You can do this with the `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => throttledReq(loaded, TIMEOUT, dispatch));
}, []);
```

The empty array at the end means that it doesn't have any dependencies, so it will only run once whenever the component is rendered. Every rerender won't call the callback.

Your `loaded` value should use a `useEffect` as well, but in this case with the `loaded` variable as a dependency. Every time `loaded` is changed (and on the first render), the callback is fired and the logic assessed.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (loaded === 0) {
    API.Post.getAllPosts(loaded)(dispatch);
  }

  if (loaded % 5 === 0) {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight * 0.6)
  }
), [loaded]);
```

Since you're trying to call a certain logic whenever a scroll position is reached, or some element is in view, I recommend you take a look at the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) which eliminates the requirement of a throttled `onscroll` function.

Comment: well the request number is fixed but now if I put loaded as a dependency the action gets called multiple times making it load about 10 posts not 5